# Código ajax não está pegando o valor dos inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um problema com o ajax, que não esta pegando os dados inseridos no formulário de email, apesar de estar enviando os emails.

Segue o código do formulário:

```js
      $(function(){
$('#nome, #email, #assunto, #message').on('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#envia').click();
    }
});

$("#envia").click(function(){
 var name = $("#nome").val(),
     emai = $("#email").val(),
     ass  = $("#assunto").val(),
     mess = $("#message").val();
    
    var campo = {
        nome: $("#nome").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        assunto: $("#assunto").val(),
        message: $("#message").val()
    };

    if(!campo.nome || !campo.assunto || !campo.email || !campo.message){
        $.alert({
        title: 'Atenção',
        content: 'Todos os campos sao obrigatorios!',
        animation: 'bottom',
        icon: 'fa fa-warning',
        animationSpeed: 700,
        keyboardEnabled: true,
        columnClass: 'col-md-4 col-md-offset-4'
        });
        return;
    }
    
 $.ajax("email.php",{
  type: "POST",
  data:{'nome': name, 'email': emai, 'assunto': ass, 'mensagem': mess} }).done(function(){
   $.alert({
             title: 'Sucesso',
             content: 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!',
             animation: 'bottom',
             icon: 'fa fa-warning',
             animationSpeed: 700,
             keyboardEnabled: true,
             columnClass: 'col-md-4 col-md-offset-4'
             });
             return;
  }).fail(function(){
   $.alert({
             title: 'Opss..',
             content: 'Ocorreu um erro durante o processo tente novamente!',
             animation: 'bottom',
             icon: 'fa fa-warning',
             animationSpeed: 700,
             keyboardEnabled: true,
             columnClass: 'col-md-4 col-md-offset-4'
             });
             return;
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="nome" class="form-control" required placeholder="Nome">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="assunto" required class="form-control" placeholder="Assunto">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <textarea name="message" id="message" id="message" required class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Sua Mensagem. "></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <button name="submit" id="envia" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Enviar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: poderia dar um pouco mais de contexto, quais dados não estão sendo pegos, poste seu HTML do formulário. Acho que assim vai conseguir uma resposta :)

Comment: nao estao sendo pegos tudo os dados que estou pedindo para pegar

Comment: adicionado a parte em html

Comment: Usa o console.log e ve até onde o seu código esta pegando os dados

Comment: dei um console.log(data) e ele me deu esse erro data is not defined

Comment: tente remover as aspas simples das suas variaveis dentro do `data`

Comment: mudou nada continua no mesmo erro

Comment: Mudou o data para `data: {
               'a' : name,
               'b' : emai,
               'c' : ass,
               'd' :mess
             }` ?

Comment: to vendo pelo breakpoint ta estranho ele ta recebendo os valores das variaveis e ta pegando

Comment: o problema pode ser no seu arquivo email.php tambem.

Comment: mas la estava certo ate eu resolver fazer com o ajax

Comment: Mesmo mudando seu data da forma que postei continua dando erro? Se sim, informe qual.

Comment: sim continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: fiz um teste pra ver se e o php e nao e nao joguei o form la encima e preenchi os campos ele me envio o email certinho

Comment: Onde está dando erro então? Se está enviando o email, quer dizer que os dados estão sendo enviados pelo ajax normalmente.

Comment: nao eu fiz o teste pelo php somente php pra ve se meu codigo php estava errado e ele nao esta errado. o erro e no ajax ele ta enviando o email mas nao ta pegando as variaveis nao esta mandando os campos preenchidos o email ele ta mandando intendeu?

Comment: ai ta dando esse erro de data is not defined

Comment: poderiam me ajudar eu refiz o ajax e consegui pegar o email agora ele esta mandando email somente com o campo email preechido e os outros campos vazio vou editar meu codigo ajax deve ser algum pequeno erro que estou deixando passar se alguem puder ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere o json que você está populando manualmente em `data` dentro do ajax e remova a virgula adicional:

Seu código está assim:

```
 $.ajax({
             url: 'email.php',
             type: 'POST',
             data: {
               a: 'name',
               b: 'emai',
               c: 'ass',
               d: 'mess'
             },
           })
```

Mude para assim:

```
 $.ajax({
             url: 'email.php',
             type: 'POST',
             data: {
               a: name,
               b: emai,
               c: ass,
               d: mess
             }
           })
```

E para pegar os dados no `email.php`  use os indices do json como indice da variavel global `$_POST`. Exemplo:

```
$name = $_POST['a'];
$email = $_POST['b'];
$assunto = $_POST['c'];
$messagem = $_POST['d'];
```

Comment: e sim obrigado cara mas ja resolvi vo marcar como resolvido percebi agora que eu tinha que passar o name que eu dei nos input e eles tinha que bater com a codificacao em php vlw ai man

Comment: @LeonardoCosta Disponha  :D. Se você notar, eu já tinha te respondido isso nos comentários, olha aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97273/c%C3%B3digo-ajax-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-pegando-o-valor-dos-inputs/97291?noredirect=1#comment197288_97273

Comment: e eu percebi agora mas ali onde esta esse a,b,c,d eu pesnava que eu poderia entrar com qualquer coisa e nao com o post do php